# Read html from current UIWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview that shows some links. When I clic on a link, it sends me some JSON. In order to display the data that is sent to me, I need :

1) detect when a link is called

2) get the json

For 2), I've tried  `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];` that returns me :

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{some JSON}</pre>
```

and `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName(\"pre\")"];` returns me an empty object. What other way do I have to get my JSON ?

And for 1) is there a UIWebView delegate methode to detect when a link is called ?

Comment: To detect that link was clicked on use
(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
e.g navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked

Comment: Hey Nicolas, have you ever found an answer? Seems no one understood your question, and I am having troubles reading JSON from UIWebView just as you had.

Comment: I have the same exact output and I'm trying to obtain just the JSON object.

Comment: I have the exact same output http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351024/ios-how-to-read-json-from-custom-uiwebview-auth

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem. I solved by this code

```
    NSString *jsonString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName(\"pre\")[0].innerHTML"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The iOS Developer Library is your best friend. Turns out that UIWebView does have a protocol that you can subscribe to.
Here's the link to the delegate callbacks: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate

The one you want is

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Implement this protocol method and you can introspect the `NSURLRequest` object for it's `NSURL` and then the rest is up to you...

Edit:
For completeness, I should mention the `- (NSData *)HTTPBody` instance method on `NSURLRequest` objects. You'll most likely find the JSON within that piece of NSData.
There is an `NSJSONSerialization` class in the Foundation framework that you can use to create `NSObject`'s out of JSON data.
Here's what you have so far...

```
// UIWebView delegate method
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  NSData *jsonData = request.HTTPBody;
  id jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: nil];
  // do stuff with the object...
  ...
  // the webview shouldn't load the request since it's going to be raw json data (or is it)
  return NO;
}
```

In theory, this code should work but only if the JSON data that you receive is pure JSON. From your question, it seems like there's a bit of HTML attached to the JSON data so you will have to implement a method to strip the data of it's HTML parts. Be wary that there is alot of fine print when it comes to converting data structures in this manner. Check out the `NSJSONSerialization` documentation to get more specific information:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Happy coding!